# Django admin search should include inline fields too

Tags: javascript, python, django, python-2.7

I am trying to include a inline field in model admin search_fields but I am not able to figure it.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from yourapp.models import Supplier, Product

class ProductInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Product

class SupplierAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ProductInline,]


admin.site.register(Supplier, SupplierAdmin)
```

Here I want to search product in SupplierAdmin class, though product is inline I am not able to get search functionality

Answer (score 0):

You need to create you custom Filter object and pass it to list_filters attribute of Admin class. Please refer to [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter) for more details

Basically what you need is to have a filter like:

```
class ProductFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
   # Human-readable title which will be displayed in the
   # right admin sidebar just above the filter options.
   title = 'Filter title'
   # Parameter for the filter that will be used in the URL query.
   parameter_name = 'name_of_parameter'

   def queryset(self, request, queryset):
      """
      Returns the filtered queryset based on the value
      provided in the query string and retrievable via
      `self.value()`.
      """
      # Compare the requested value (either '80s' or 'other')
      # to decide how to filter the queryset.
      if self.value():
         return queryset.filter(product_FIELD_YOU_WANT_TO_FILTER=self.value())
      else:
         return queryset

class SupplierAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   inlines = [ProductInline,]
   list_filter = (ProductFilter,)
```